# notepad++ to start with new window

Tags: notepad++

How can you set notepad++ to always start in a new window?

Whenever I open it, it always starts with the last saved document I have.

I know you can click the button new window or use alt f6, but is there a way to open without having to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Settings > Preferences > MISC. > Remember current session for next launch

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This option was ticked but it has to be cleared for it to work.